# Can TestCafe reults be tracked in HP ALM?

Tags: automated-tests, testcafe, hp-alm, test-reporting, test-results

HP ALM is my current test management tool and I'm currently planning on using TestCafe for automation. I would like to know if I can have the results from my test runs in TestCafe shown in HP ALM?

Is it possible to make an integration or automatically generate reports in TestCafe that can then be imported to HP ALM? I have read about reporters for TestCafe but I'm unsure about the extend of their functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) - it can parse reports from various testing tools.
For TestCafe, you can use xunit reporter to produce xUnit reports, e.g.:
`testcafe chrome test.js -r xunit:result.xml`
This will generate result.xml file which can be then uploaded to ALM with Bumblebee Server and CI plugin for Jenkins/TeamCity/Bamboo.
Please refer to [the documentation](https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/ci-integration/jenkins/).

Disclaimer: I'm developing Bumblebee Server

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any HP ALM plug-ins for TestCafe at this time.

You can create your own reporter for HP ALM by following the instructions from the documentation: [Reporter Plugin](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/extend-testcafe/reporter-plugin.html).